# Dynamically create craft.entries

Tags: templating, params

Basically I want to add certain parameters to my 'craft.entries' based on whether a variable is set:

```
{# Get a start date value from the URL (my use case) #}
{% set start_date = craft.request.getSegment(3) %} {# e.g. '2015-12-10' #}

{% if start_date != "" %}

  {# Create .after() param #}
    {% set startDateQuery = ".after(" ~ start_date ~ ")" %}

{% else %}

    {# If there is no start date then set the param as "" so nothing happens #}
    {% set startDateQuery = "" %}

{% endif %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.section('events') ~ startDateQuery %}

{% paginate entries as pageInfo, pageEntries %}
  ... Do stuff
```

I've tried this other ways as well, but this one seemed the most appropriate. Either way, it's not working and I was wondering if anyone might know why - or have a suggestion of a better method?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the chained syntax, you should build a parameter object and pass that in to `craft.entries`, like so:

```
{# Get a start date value from the URL (my use case) #}
{% set start_date = craft.request.getSegment(3) %} {# e.g. '2015-12-10' #}

{# Create a parameter object, with default values #}
{% set params = { section: 'events' } %}

{# If start_date exists, add the after parameter to the object #}
{% if start_date != "" %}
    {% set params = params | merge({ after: start_date }) %}
{% endif %}

{# Get the entries by passing the parameters to craft.entries() #}
{% set entries = craft.entries(params) %}
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! I figured this would be the best way to it, but I've not seen it done this way before so I wasn't sure where to start. Cheers mate!